# spring boot application.properties does not work in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, application.properties

I'm using spring boot with IntelliJ, and I'm trying to change the port of my application from 8080(default) to 8090, or etc. So I edited my application.properties file like below:

```
server.port=8090
```

But it seems that IntelliJ cannot recognize the change of this file. First I thought that this is the problem about the cache of gradle, but it still does not work even after I cleared my cache.

So, what's the problem?? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you put  the `application.properties` file? Is it under `/src/main/resources` ? Is "resources" folder colored with "blue" color in IntelliJ (does it recognize the resources folder)?

Comment: yes, it is in `/src/main/resouces/`.

Comment: Could you check the "target" (director with compiled classes) and make sure that there is `application.properties` with your changes exist?

Comment: is their any message on console?

Comment: Please check whether this is property is getting overridden by application-{ENV}.properties file.

Comment: Also check the textual output from when you are starting the application and see what port is reported and if there are any errors/warnings. Also check that this port is not occupied by some other process on your machine.